# problem when manipulating numbers in ASCII to stay only in range of letters

Tags: c, cs50

So I need to shift letters in an a given word to the right of the alphabet. But, when it gets to 'z' or 'Z', I need it to loop around back to 'A' or 'a'. I thought I could do this by for each character by adding conditions(if passes z's or Z's numerical ASCII value) through the ASCII letters. And if they are met then it should subtract 26 but it isnt. But for some reasons the variables are not abiding by the conditions ( for example if I need to shift 'o' 13 to the right it goes to | , which is correct for ASCII, but I need to it go to 'A'or 'a' and then continue adding the key.

The overall method works because shifting words by one does work. For example, Hello +1 right = Ifmmp. It's just the conditions. My code currently does compile and run.

I'll briefly explain my code. First I user the command line argument to get the amount the word needs to be shifted to the right (**key**). Then, if it fits the requirements, then it asks for the the word that is supposed to be shifted (**plaintext**). And then my problem of conditions. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in restricting.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
  int x;
  string plaintext;
  int cyphertext;
//turns into number (if applicable) and checks requiremnts (1-99)
  char *c = argv[1];
  int beforekey = atoi(c);
  int key = beforekey % 26;
  if (key >= 1 && key <= 26)
  {
//asks for text
    plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    x = strlen(plaintext);
// int i = 0; while (i < x ) { i++;  }
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
      {

      if ((plaintext[i] + key) >= 65 && (plaintext[i] + key) <= 90
      && (plaintext[i] + key) >= 97 && (plaintext[i] + key) <= 122)
          {
          plaintext[i] += key - 26;
          }

      else if ((plaintext[i] + key) > 0 && (plaintext[i] + key) <= 64 
      && (plaintext[i] + key) >= 91 && (plaintext[i] + key) <= 96
      && (plaintext[i] + key) >= 123 && (plaintext[i] + key) <= 127)
        {
          continue;
        }

      else 
        {
          plaintext[i] +=  key;
        }

        }
    printf("cyphertext: ");
    printf("%s", plaintext);


  }
// if didnt meet requirments

  else
  {
    printf("./caesar key\n");
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` has *two* conflicting ranges. It will *always* be *false* (e.g. `x <= 90 && x >= 97` can *never* be true). You have to split this into two `if` statements. Or, you need `||`. The two `if` solution is probably simpler to understand.

Using some intermediate variables can simplify the code rather than replicating `plaintext[i] + key` everywhere.

Note that you [probably] don't want to encipher the nul terminator so you may need `> 0` to be `>= 0`.

Here's a refactored version. I've not compiled nor tested this. But, it should help you to understand your code a bit better:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int x;
    string plaintext;
    int cyphertext;

    //turns into number (if applicable) and checks requiremnts (1-99)
    char *c = argv[1];
    int beforekey = atoi(c);
    int key = beforekey % 26;

    if (key >= 1 && key <= 26) {
        //asks for text
        plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        x = strlen(plaintext);

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            char *ptr = &plaintext[i];
            int chr = *ptr;
            int c2 = chr + key;

            if (c2 >= 65 && c2 <= 90) {
                *ptr += key - 26;
                continue;
            }

            if (c2 >= 97 && c2 <= 122) {
                *ptr += key - 26;
                continue;
            }

            if (c2 >= 0 && c2 <= 64)
                continue;

            if (c2 >= 91 && c2 <= 96)
                continue;

            if (c2 >= 123 && c2 <= 127)
                continue;

            *ptr += key;
        }

        printf("cyphertext: ");
        printf("%s", plaintext);

    }
// if didnt meet requirments

    else {
        printf("./caesar key\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Craig Estey’s answer regarding the conditional operators, a simple way to implement looping through numbers can be by using the modulo operator. As an example, take the range of ASCII values for capital letters (65 - 90) and lowercase letters (97-122). Knowing that the alphabet consists of 26 letters, we can loop through the range by:

```
// Uppercase Letters
if(plaintext[i] >= 'A' && plaintext[i] <= 'Z')
    plaintext[i] = (((plaintext[i] % 65) + (key % 26)) % 26) + 65;

// Lowercase Letters
if(plaintext[i] >= 'a' && plaintext[i] <= 'z')
    plaintext[i] = (((plaintext[i] % 97) + (key % 26)) % 26) + 97;
else
    // Handle symbols and special cases
```

(Assuming key is either a character or integer that holds an ASCII value)

This will loop all the values within the range 65-90 or 97-122 without the use of conditional operators except to classify the character type (lowercase or uppercase).

I hope this helps!